# Can't add downloaded plugin to Cordova/Phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, npm, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

How can I get a plugin to work by installing it NOT from the repository.
Each plugin I try to install using `phonegap plugin add <<git repository>>` always results in different errors, because windows + npm just doesn't want to work for me...

This is the plugin I need: https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard

My steps:

1. Download Git repository
2. Run `phonegap plugin add <<downloaded and extracted directory>>`
3. Remove and add android platform (yes it says that it installed the plugin)
4. Start Phonegap Developer app

But `cordova.plugins.clipboard` is still undefined. Do I have to put the clipboard.js file somewhere or reference it? If so, which version? 
The one in the clipboard project or the one phonegap automatically creates within the platform/android directory (it puts a "define" around it). I actually tried both, but the object was still undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clipboard plugin does not have a `package.json` present which is why you are getting the error. You can either add a `package.json` file to the plugin or you can install it with the `--nofetch` flag:

```
cordova/phonegap plugin add https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard.git --nofetch
```

Since cordova 7.0.0 `npm install` is run by default when adding a new plugin which causes an error if no `package.json` is present. You can find the release notes for cordova 7.0.0 [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I actually used npm init to create the package.json as I realized it was missing.

Comment: Then try the `--nofetch` option. A don't donwload the plugin, install it from git like in my example.

Comment: The download worked. Finally I am able to download from repositories! Unfortunately the object remains undefined. Do I have to reference the clipboard.js in my index.html file? And do I have to put the .js file in my www directory? I tried different combinations but none of them worked.

Comment: No you don't have to do anything, just install it and then use it. But the plugin wont work with the "Phonegap Developer App" you have to run it on a device yourself using `cordova run android --device`. You can find the plugins which are supported in the "Phonegap Developer App" [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/troubleshoot-faq/).

Comment: wow, and I wasted so much time on this, trying different things... Thank´s a bunch for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help! :-)